# Reducing the size of .rodata

Tags: c++, linker, embedded

I'm crosscompiling C++ in Gentoo for an ARM Cortex M3 (Maple Mini), but seem to have hit a roof with the memory resources when linking the elf-file

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-none-eabi/ld: build/maple_mini.elf section `.rodata' will not fit in region `rom'
/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-none-eabi/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 1508 bytes
```

This post is a question about how to reduce the size of the contents of .rodata, to be able to complete the linking of the elf-file.

I have stripped the included code, and am compiling with the following relevant options.

```
CXXFLAGS = -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,-gc-sections ...
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-gc-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti ...
```

Still, the .rodata in the map-file (with which I am quite unfamiliar) contains what seems to be some kind of type information for each of the classes in the program. Some map-file excerpts (note. MPU6050 is a SuperSensor<> which is a Sensor<>, in a C++ sense)

```
    0x000000000801d6c0       0x28 .../libsyrup.a(MPU6050.o)
    0x000000000801d6c0    _ZTVN5syrup6SensorILi6EEE
.rodata._ZTVN5syrup11SuperSensorILi6EEE    0x000000000801d6e8       0x28 .../libsyrup.a(MPU6050.o)
    0x000000000801d6e8                _ZTVN5syrup11SuperSensorILi6EEE
.rodata._ZTVN5syrup7MPU6050E  0x000000000801d710       0x28 .../libsyrup.a(MPU6050.o)
     0x000000000801d710                _ZTVN5syrup7MPU6050E
.rodata._ZTVN5syrup6SensorILi1EEE
     0x000000000801d738                 0x28 .../libsyrup.a(MS5611.o)
     0x000000000801d738                _ZTVN5syrup6SensorILi1EEE
.rodata._ZTVN5syrup11SuperSensorILi1EEE
            0x000000000801d760          0x28 .../libsyrup.a(MS5611.o)
            0x000000000801d760                _ZTVN5syrup11SuperSensorILi1EEE
...
            0x000000000801ee24          0x6f3 .../libstdc++.a(cp-demangle.o)
                                        0x730 (size before relaxing)
*fill*         0x000000000801f517       0x1 
.rodata        0x000000000801f518       0x14 .../libgcc.a(unwind-arm.o)
.rodata        0x000000000801f52c       0x23c .../libc.a(lib_a-strerror.o)
.rodata.str1.4    0x000000000801f768    0x635 .../libc.a(lib_a-strerror.o)
                                        0x63c (size before relaxing)
```

So,
    lib_a-strerror.o
and
    cp-demangle.o
seems to be what takes up most space, although I guess these are quite vital.

So, my question is, what further steps can I take to reduce (or restructure the code) the .rodata section, and what exactly is stored there? Any suggestions are welcome! I am fairly new to the deeper workings of compilation and linking, but learning.

Comment: These are error message strings linked in from the C and C++ runtime libraries.  They tell the user why your program crashed.  Getting rid of them would require rewriting the runtime libraries, not exactly practical but it has been done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem may not necessarily be in the rodata section as such - it's just that that's the guy that didn't sit down in time at the muscal chairs event. In other words, rodata in itself isn't what's too large, but the WHOLE IMAGE is too large to fit. The solution would be to look at your entire code, data and rodata in your system, and see if any of it stands out.

Removing unnecessary code (or strings) in general would be the key point here. If there is nothing that can be removed, then you'll have to find a different way to solve the problem. One way may be to compress the code and data, and uncompress it into RAM (assuming there's significantly more RAM than ROM on the target system). This is not an unheard of problem, but it's never really that easy to fix - unless someone has done some really bad coding and added some hundreds of kilobytes of code. If you have a version control system, and you know of a version that does fit, it may be a good thing to check exactly how much spare space there is - if it's suddenly grown a lot, check if someone has added some massive static data structures or some such.

Comment: Thanks,
In further cleanup I ended up finding a stray erraneous assert include which seemed to be a major root of including parts of the standard library which cluttered the .elf. The major point here seems to be to reduce the dependency on the stdlib (including new and delete operators) to a bare minimum.

Answer (score 6):

The underlying issue isn't that the `.rodata` section is too big, necessarily -- you're just running out of ROM space in general. (The linker just happens to be hitting the limit while it's linking in that section.)

Removing any calls to functions such as `perror`, `strerror`, and company should end up dropping the dependency on `strerror.o`, which should save you the kilobyte and a half you're over by. There may be other, easier ways you can make those same savings, though -- it all depends on your application.